# Knockout with not creating property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a little problem.
My fiddle is

http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25524/

**JS**

```
var helloVm = function()
{
    var vm=this;
    vm.obj1=ko.observable({});
    vm.obj2=ko.observable({});
    vm.test = function()
    {
        alert("fffff");
        alert("Obj 1 name is "+vm.obj1().name); 
        alert("Obj 2 name is "+vm.obj2().name); 
    };

};
ko.applyBindings(new helloVm(), document.getElementById('foo'));
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo">
    <div>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:obj1().name" />
    </div>
    <div data-bind="with:obj2()" style="margin-top:2px">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:name" />
    </div>
    <button data-bind="click:test">Test</button>
</div>
```

First case is binding to unexisting property of object directly
And second case is binding to unexisting property of object via "with" binding

In second case(using "with") knockout doesn't create property in object.
But it'll be created in first case.

What kind of problem do I have?

Comment: can't you just initialize the properties, like this `vm.obj1=ko.observable({ name: '' });` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25529/)

I hope this is what you are after.

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo">
    <div>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: obj1().name" />
    </div>
    <div data-bind="with:obj2()" style="margin-top:2px">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:name" />
    </div>
    <button data-bind="click:test">Test</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

> The property `name` does not exist and therefore you can not assign a
>   value to it. Below I have set the observables to have an object with
>   the `name` property.

```
var helloVm = function () {
    var vm = this;
    // Added an object property of name
    vm.obj1 = ko.observable({
        name: ''
    });
    // Added an object property of name = Result
    vm.obj2 = ko.observable({
        name: 'Result'
    });
    vm.test = function () {
        alert("fffff");
        alert("Obj 1 name is " + vm.obj1().name);
        alert("Obj 2 name is " + vm.obj2().name);
    };

};
ko.applyBindings(new helloVm(), document.getElementById('foo'));
```

Comment: I want to create property in object automatically via knockout. I admit that if I use it without "with" it works properly. But if I use "with" keyword all fails

Comment: @takayoshi You could write a custom binding handler to create a property, but the standard handlers do not.